# How to multiline regex but stop after first match?

Tags: regex, multiline, non-greedy

I need to match any string that has certain characteristics, but I think enabling the `/m` flag is breaking the functionality.

What I know:

1. The string will start and end with quotation marks.
2. The string will have the following words. "the", "fox", and "lazy".
3. The string may have a line break in the middle.
4. The string will never have an at sign (used in the regex statement)

My problem is, if I have the string twice in a single block of text, it returns once, matching everything between the first quote mark and last quote mark with the required words in-between.

Here is my regex:

```
/^"the[^@]*fox[^@]*lazy[^@]*"$/gim
```

[And a Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/ahVkw1/2).

Here is my understanding of the statement. Match where the string starts with `"the` and there is the word `fox` and `lazy` (in that order) somewhere before the string ends with `"`. Also ignore newlines and case-sensitivity.

The most common answer to limiting is `(.*?)` But it doesn't work with new lines. And putting `[^@?]*` doesn't work because it adds the `?` to the list of things to ignore.

**So how can I keep the "match everything until ___" from skipping until the last instance while still being able to ignore newlines?**

*This is not a duplicate of anything else I can find because this deals with multi-line matching, and those don't.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, all your quantifiers need to be non-greedy so you can just use the flag *ungreedy*: `U`.

```
/^"the[^@]*fox[^@]*lazy[^@]*"$/gimU
```

[Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ahVkw1/3).

Answer (score 1):

The answer, which was figured out while typing up this question, may seem ridiculously obvious.

Put the `?` after the `*`, not inside the brackets. Parenthesis and Brackets are not analogous, and the `?` should be relative to the `*`.

Corrected regex:

```
/^"the[^@]*?fox[^@]*?lazy[^@]*?"$/gim
```

[Example from Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ItO1HM/3/).

The long and the short of this is:

#### Non-greedy, multi-line matching can be achieved with `[^@]*?`

(substituting `@` for something you don't want to match)